# AwesomeGrid random rendering issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, grid

I'm using **AwesomeGrid** (http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/) in a project asp.net mvc architecture based.
Sometimes the grid is not well rendered (usually when it is included in a popup) as the picture shows:

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Could you please be specific about your issue(about not well rendered)? Do you mean the controls doesn't fit within the pop up?

Comment: the grid won't show (neither records in it)... only the grey line I've posted in the question is showed... it is the same behaviour when you have two grid with the same id in a page